# debug_backtrace в высоконагруженном сервисе

Tags: php, логирование

Нагрузка на **nginx** в час пик достигает до 1000 запросов в секунду. На сколько критично будет использовать debug_backtrace для логирования точек вызова методов где вылетела критичная ошибка сервиса. Не очень хочется в логер постоянно передавать название класса или файл которые на текущией момент исполняется.

Comment: ¿"высокая" нагрузка в 1000 запросов / c, печать в лог как основное средство отладки? Это все конечно полный колхоз, но если уж хочется, то запускайте отладку воспроизводя нагрузку на тестовом сервере.

Comment: Не основное средство отладки, а больше для мониторинга через Nagios

Comment: непонятно, причем здесь 1000 запросов на нужникс. Из них 900 на статику и 100 остается к скриптам, которые могут выдать ошибку. Но главное - при чем здесь нормальные запросы, если речь идет об ошибочных. Они-то как часто бывают?

Comment: @Ипатьев, статики вообще нет, поступают звонки от абонентов на Asterisk PBX который в свою очередь дергает ядро сервиса через HTTP. При большом кол-ве звонков бывает периодически подсыпает. Нагрузочные тесты само собой проведем, чисто теоретически уже можно догодаться что обращению к стеку вызова функций, операция не из дешевых, но возможно кто то уже сталкивался с подобным и поделился бы опытом

Comment: да какая разница - дешевая операция, или нет - если она вызывается не при каждом запросе, а только при ошибках?